# Rename Navigation Property in Entity Framework 5 does not update code

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I would like to rename a navigation property and access that object in code by the new name I gave. I have renamed one of my user properties to a more meaningful name rather than 1,2,3...etc.

In this example, I have renamed OGSMUser5 to OGSMUserResponsible in the model diagram.

I then tried to access this in code, but it can't find my renamed property OGSMUserResponsible.

```
@contImprovement.OGSMUserResponsible.FullName
```

When I look at the code in the model generated from Entity Data Model, I see that the code did not change for the newly renamed model, which explains why I can't access it.

```
    public virtual OGSMUser OGSMUser { get; set; }
    public virtual OGSMUser OGSMUser1 { get; set; }
    public virtual OGSMUser OGSMUser2 { get; set; }
    public virtual OGSMUser OGSMUser3 { get; set; }
    public virtual OGSMUser OGSMUser4 { get; set; }
    public virtual OGSMUser OGSMUser5 { get; set; }
```

I have seen somewhat similar questions to this, but the answers I have seen I can't believe is the only option. They have been manually creating a new property with the name you want (what I renamed mine to in the navigation property) in a partial class and return the navigation property with the number in the name to help clean it up. I can't believe that this is the best way to accomplish what I am looking for.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably didn't run the [T4 template transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx).

Just right click your **.tt files** (they are under your .edmx file in the Solution Explorer tree) and **run** them. Alternatively, you can **run all tt** by clicking the button in Visual Studio's toolbar.

[image: T4 templates run in Visual Studio]

Comment: Thanks, that got it. I don't see the icon you show in your screen shot, but I was able to right click and run custom tool on the .tt file and it changed the code to what I was wanting. What do I need to add to my view to get the button to run all like you show?

Comment: @bryanware I don't remember having changed anything in Visual Studio. Maybe because I chose "Common Developer" when I installed VS. You could customize your toolbar though.